# Adjacency List structure in HBase

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase

I'm trying to implement the following graph reduction algorithm in

- The graph is an undirected weighted graph
- I want to strip away all nodes with only two neighbors
- and update the weights

Have a look at the following illustration:

[Algorithm reduce graph http://public.kungi.org/graph-reduction.png](http://public.kungi.org/graph-reduction.png)

The algorithm shall transform the upper graph into the lower one. Eliminate node 2 and update the weight of the edge to: w(1-3) = w(1-2)+w(2-3)

Since I have a very large graph I'm doing this with MapReduce.

My Question is how to represent the graph in HBase. I thought about building an adjacency list structure in HBase like this:

Column families: nodes, neighbors
1 -> 2, 6, 7
...

Is there a nicer way to do this?

Answer (score 0):

Adjacency lists are the most frequently recommended structure.

You could use each node ID as the row ID and neighbor IDs as column qualifiers, with the weights as values.